# R crashes whenever I don't write a sqldf query perfectly

Tags: r, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, sqldf

> sessionInfo()
>
> R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
> Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
>
> Matrix products: default BLAS:
> /home/roughmar/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so LAPACK:
> /home/roughmar/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.so
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
> [3] LC_TIME=en_IE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8      [5]
> LC_MONETARY=en_IE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8     [7]
> LC_PAPER=en_IE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                   [9]
> LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             [11]
> LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
> datasets  methods   base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] compiler_3.4.1
> R6_2.2.1        magrittr_1.5    IRdisplay_0.4.4  [5] pbdZMQ_0.2-6
> tools_3.4.1     crayon_1.3.2    uuid_0.1-2       [9] stringi_1.1.5
> IRkernel_0.7.1  jsonlite_1.5    stringr_1.2.0   [13] digest_0.6.12
> repr_0.10       evaluate_0.10

Whenever I load the sqldf library I am greeted with:

> Loading required package: gsubfn
>
> Loading required package: proto
>
> Could not load tcltk.  Will use slower R code instead.
>
> Loading required package: RSQLite

Any sqldf query I write runs perfectly and the results are as expected.
The issue rises when I make a mistake on an expression, like an extra comma, or mispelling a variable, or whatever you might imagine that would usually output an error.

I don't get an error - it just crashes.
Tested both on Rstudio and jupyter - the kernel just dies and needs to be restarted. After a while it gets tiring cause I need to reload all the variables again, every time.

I am aware that this is quite vague but am more than willing to provide with whatever info that might be needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would surmise that this is on Anaconda, or more generally on mixing Conda and plain R.

On my system---standard Ubuntu (17.04) R (3.4.2) binaries via CRAN mirror with standard sqldf---it all works just fine:

```
R> a1r <- head(warpbreaks)     ## initial `help(sqdf)` example
R> a1s <- sqldf("select * from warpbreaks limit 6")
R> identical(a1r, a1s)
[1] TRUE
R> sqldf("selectFOO * from warpbreaks limit 6 BAR")   # no termination on error
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  near "selectFOO": syntax error
R> 
R> sqldf("select * from warpbreaks limit 2")
  breaks wool tension
1     26    A       L
2     30    A       L
R>
```

Binaries can be incompatible when toolchains get broken.

I would suggest to *locally rebuild* the packages involved, plus their dependencies.  So at a minimum RSQLite and DBI, the problem of course is that these pull in a bazillion other packages.

You could consider running in Docker as well.

Or, do as I (and bajillion other people) do:  don't let Conda near your R stack.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Uninstalling conda's R and getting it from the source.
I realized I had an issue with dependencies from a couple of packages that just didn't workout together.

Reinstalling R as a standalone made everything work nice and dandy.

On a completely different note - how is ubuntu 17.04 working out for ya?

Thank you so much for spending the time on your answer.

Comment: i) Good you have it working. ii) You don't need to reinstall R -- many of us use the [R binaries for Ubuntu from CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) (based on the Debian package I maintain.  iii) 17.04 is fine, as all previous Ubuntu releases; been upgrading twice a year for a decade.  iv)  If it all works, please feel free to accept (click on tickmark only you as OP see) and upvote (click on up trinagle) -- that is how StackOverflow "works".

Comment: is bajillion >> bazillion or vice versa?

Comment: It's a Heisenquantity.  Whenever you compare it, it changes.  But I think either is further than I can count.

Comment: So should I edit for consistent use of baJillion or baZillion?  A deep question.